# CS50 PSET 3 Runoff vote function confusion

Tags: c, cs50

The voter function is supposed to check the names in casted ballots in a runoff election and if the voters ballot names match a candidates name it records that candidates name in the preferences array as that voters choice. I'm going to post the source code and the vote function below.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            preferenes[voter][rank] = i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The solution for the vote function is not mine, I'm just having trouble understanding where [voter] [rank] comes from? The variables aren't initialized anywhere else and I just don't understand how they're being used in the array if they're not given any values. I'm also confused as to why it equals i. I know this is most likely a noob question and has a very simple answer. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Apparently write-in candidates are not allowed in this election :-(. Regardless, `vote` is clearly broken. It always returns false. The values for `voter` and `rank` in that function are parameters provided to the function by the arguments the caller provides. In this case, they're doming from those `i` and `j` loops in `main` (the only place in the entire source code where `vote` is invoked: `if (!vote(i, j, name))` ).

Comment: @WhozCraig — in many places, the concept of 'write-in candidate' doesn't exist.

Comment: There's a fragment with nested `for` loops which calls the `vote()` function with the voter ID (`i`, a number 0..(voter_count - 1)) and rank (`j`, a number 0..(candidate_count - 1)).

Comment: @WhozCraig --so declaring vote(i , j, name) where the function is called would pass the use of the for loops to whatever parameters provided in the function and I can call them inside the function when I need to use the loops? Just want to make sure I understand it correctly before moving on to the next TODO

Comment: @tjgribbin That's not a declaration; that's in invocation. The values of `i` and `j` are passed as arguments to the implementation of that function, which uses those values for `voter` and `rank` respectively. Trust me; get a good book on C. Questions like this are covered in extreme detail in such tomes.

Comment: @WhozCraig I will definitely look into books on C. Are the values of i and j passed after or before heir updates with i++ and j++ respectively? or is it passing the use of the loop into the function with voter and rank? Going to the library today to look for books on C. I appreciate your help immensely brother.

Answer (score -1):

Pay attention to the function call and what is there and how it is transmitted =)

```
if (!vote(i, j, name))
{
    printf("Invalid vote.\n");
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).